# CORS error when using App script to write data to google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, cors

I'm using the App script to post data from my web app and write into Sheet but failed with CORS error tried few code suggested by others

Here is the code on App script:

```
function doPost(e) {
var params = e.postData;
var selected = params.selectedYear;
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1GeHldpOtB9CZAQjVZH66HJvPAAj7"); 
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

 sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1).setValue(selected);

return ContentService.createTextOutput("success");
```

}

Web app code:

```
fetch(apiUri, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: {"selectedYear": 1998},
  headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=utf-8',
  } }).then(response => {
  console.log("success:", response);}).catch(err => {
  console.log("Error:" + err);
```

});

Error shown:

[image]

Hope can get some idea from here, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### Google Apps Script:

```js
function doPost(e) {
  var params = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var selected = params.selectedYear;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1GeHldpOtB9CZAQjVZH66HJvPAAj7"); 
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1).setValue(selected);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("success");
}
```

#### Javascript:

```js
const apiUri = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec"; // Please set your Web Apps URL.

fetch(apiUri, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({ "selectedYear": 1998 }),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=utf-8',
  }
})
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(response => {
    console.log("success:", response);
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log("Error:" + err);
  });
```

- By this modification, when this modified Javascript is run, `success: success` is shown in the console. And, the value of `1998` is put into column "A" of "Sheet1".

#### Note:

- **When you modify the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the details of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script (Author: me)](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: I didn't realize now is using postData to get the value from web app! Thanks so much Tanaike! :D